# ASP.NET MVC using DevExpress - Databinding issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview, devexpress

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC and DevExpress libraries manipulate data from an Oracle source. I'm using the GridView componenent and I'm populating it like this :

**Controller**

```
        public ActionResult ContractsPartial(string contract)
        {
            NESR.Entities db = new NESR.Entities();
            var model = db.AIR_CONTRACT.Where(c => c.MODUSR.ToUpper().Contains(contract.ToUpper()));
            return PartialView(model.ToList());
        }
```

**View**

```
@model NESR.Models.SearchViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "NESR - Main Page";
}

<h2>Main Page</h2>

    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.ContractId, new { @id = "tbxContract"})
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSub" value="Submit" />
    </div>


<div id="grid"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            var contract = $("#tbxContract").val();
            $.get('/Home/ContractsPartial', { contract: contract }).success(function (html) {
                $('#grid').html(html);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Everything works fine doing like that and I'm getting my DevExpress GridView without issue. However, as I'm getting a lot of results, when I'm trying to display the second page of my grid, the ContractsPartial method is called and as I didn't enter any value in my text box, it returns an empty grid.

Why is it doing this? Any idea guys?

Comment: There could be an issue with CallbackRouteValues setting of your GridView. Post a code of your ContractsPartialView

Comment: I also advise you to use built in filter capability of DevExpress GridView. It seems that now you use it only for data presentation, and as a server-side component it is quite heavy if you're not using its main features